# AWS CodeBuild - Get Webhook Body in buildspec.yml

Tags: github, aws-codebuild

If I have a build that triggered by a github webhook in AWS CodeBuild, is there a way for me to inspect the content of the webhook body that triggered the build from my buildspec.yml file? Or is this content just lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to trigger a codebuild build from Github, you're going to need to be able to consume post data from Github and translate that into a call to codebuild. In that translation layer, just take what you need from the webhook and apply it to your codebuild build environment. One of the ways you can pass data into your codebuild build is through environment variables. I am not sure how you intend to trigger codebuild builds, but I assume you would need a translation layer that consumes the webhook and ultimately launches a codebuild build.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported today. Providing webhook payload as a preconfigured environment variable is a feature request CodeBuild team is aware of. Relevant forum post here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269699

Outside of buildspec, you could achieve this by looking at the "initiator" field of your CodeBuild console/UI or BatchGetBuilds API response. This will give the GitHub hookshot id which you may then use to look up your webhook payload in GitHub.

Comment: The initiator appears to be the same across all webgooks. In addition there would be a race condition there.

Comment: I'm guessing a  relay (possibly via lambda) to invoke the build and pass in the payload via an ENV is about the only option.